# how can i remove xml version from xml file?

Tags: libxml2

```
enter code here
```

code section

```
      xmlTextWriterPtr XMLWriter = xmlNewTextWriterFilename("example.xml",0);
      xmlTextWriterStartDocument(XMLWriter, NULL, NULL, NULL);

      xmlTextWriterStartElement(XMLWriter,BAD_CAST "Powersettings");
      xmlTextWriterSetIndent(XMLWriter,1);
      xmlTextWriterWriteElement(XMLWriter,BAD_CAST "PowerScheme",BAD_CAST "Testing");
      xmlTextWriterEndElement(XMLWriter);
      xmlTextWriterEndElement(XMLWriter);

      xmlTextWriterEndDocument(XMLWriter);
      xmlFreeTextWriter(XMLWriter);
      xmlCleanupCharEncodingHandlers();
      xmlCleanupParser();
```

here is my code which creates xml, libxml2 is the library used here.

```
xml contents,
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Powersettings>
 <PowerScheme>Testing</PowerScheme>
</Powersettings>
```

could you plz help me how to remove the "" part from my xml.

Answer (score 2):

Simply omit the call to `xmlTextWriterStartDocument`. Note that you still must call `xmlTextWriterEndDocument`, though.